# Memory usage of ScrollViewer in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, memory, windows-phone-8

I'm wondering if anyone know of a way to set a property or setting on a phone app so that the ScrollViewer uses less of a memory cache. I currently have an app that displays images on the screen, and even with an algorithm that makes sure that only images that are close to or intersect the screen are visible, I still run out of memory occasionally when I happen to be zoomed in with lots of images nearby.

As an example, the XAML below would eat up 125MB out of 300, and that's with just blank white canvases.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="DemoScroller.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Canvas Width="2000" Height="8000">
                <Canvas Width="990" Height="1990" Background="White"/>
                <Canvas Width="990" Height="1990" Canvas.Left="1010" Background="White"/>
                <Canvas Width="990" Height="1990" Canvas.Top="2000" Background="White"/>
                <Canvas Width="990" Height="1990" Canvas.Left="1010" Canvas.Top="2000" Background="White"/>
                <Canvas Width="990" Height="1990" Canvas.Top="4000" Background="White"/>
                <Canvas Width="990" Height="1990" Canvas.Left="1010" Canvas.Top="4000" Background="White"/>
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I can't use a listbox or something like that, as the images don't really line up this nicely in my app.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

Making an image invisible doesn't stop it being decoded into its uncompressed form which takes a lot of memory, especially if it is large.

You will need a more efficient way of "virtualizing" your images that unloads the images completely when they are out of view. That is what LongListSelector can give you. ScrollViewer doesn't do this.

Comment: Even though the images take up room when their visibility is set to collapsed, this is peanuts compared to what the ScrollViewer will eat when you actually display them. Even if I replaced and discarded every image in my app with a blank rectangle, it would still run out of memory really fast.